# Generic Spring Bean - duplicating type param

Tags: java, spring, generics

I'm using Spring 4.
I have the following Java Config snippet:

```
@Bean
public Service<FooType> serviceBean() {
  return new ServiceImpl<FooType>(FooType.class);
}
```

And the following Spring Bean:

```
public class ServiceImpl<T> implements Service {

private final Class<T> clazz;

  public ValidateOrderServiceImpl(final Class<T> clazz)
      this.clazz = clazz;
   }
}
```

I would prefer to not have to duplicate the type parameter, but if I dont pass in as a constructor, T is null, i.e. the following does not work. Is this expected. I have seen some related posts, which discuss erasure - and also how the type parameter can be used to resolve the correct bean to use - but have not seen a definitive on my question...

```
// Java Config Snippet (desired)
@Bean
public Service<FooType> serviceBean() {
  return new ServiceImpl<FooType>();
}
```

// Spring Bean (desired)

```
public class ServiceImpl<T> implements Service {

// T populated..
private final Class<T> clazz;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. _`T` is `null`_ is not a statement that makes sense in the Java language. `T` is a type variable. `null` is a value. Do you mean `clazz` is `null`? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, I meant clazz is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you had originally is fine and (pretty much) the only way to get the `Class` object for the corresponding type argument.

You can get rid of the explicit type argument here

```
@Bean
public Service<FooType> serviceBean() {
    return new ServiceImpl<>(FooType.class);
    //                    ^^
}
```